# Getting mysqlnd error when using Snow Leopard's Apache

Tags: mysql, apache, osx-snow-leopard

After installing Snow Leopard I got the following error when connecting to a remote MySQL server:

`mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication`

What I don't get is why it's working fine with MAMP when I only start MAMP's Apache, but I get this error with Snow Leopard's build in Apache. Is it because MAMP has some MySQL files locally? Do I still need to install MySQL locally when I try to connect to a remote server? Any clue as to how to fix this on my side without messing around with the server? Preferably Apache only — don't want to install anything I don't need.

<s>**Edit: solution**

Turned out PHP wasn't loading any php.ini file. A `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini` did the trick. First it was only loading php-mysqlnd, now php-mysql as well, and all is fine.</s>

Hmm, I was wrong, this doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any luck with this? I'm having the same exact issue. I tried resetting the password using both pre 4.1 and post 4.1 authentication with no avail.

EDIT::

My mysql server had the use old passwords option set in the configuration file, so the result of PASSWORD() and OLD_PASSWORD() returned the same 16 digit hash.

I ran SELECT PASSWORD('mysecret') on a different mysql server that uses new passwords to get the hash, then ran SET PASSWORD FOR  'myuser'@'%' = '*THEHASHFROMTHESELECTSTATEMENT';.

hth

Answer (score 0):

Try re-setting your user-pw on the MySQL-Server.
This way the password should be stored in the new format.

However, your mysql-library shipped with Snow Leopard might be compiled without support for old passwords.

Even on a live-server it should be okay to create a new db-user, so can check with a new user-account if you don't want to change the existing one.

> What I don't get is why it's working
>   fine with MAMP when I only start
>   MAMP's Apache, but I get this error
>   with Snow Leopard's build in Apache.
>   Is it because MAMP has some MySQL
>   files locally? Do I still need to
>   install MySQL locally when I try to
>   connect to a remote server? Any clue
>   as to how to fix this on my side
>   without messing around with the
>   server? Preferably Apache only — don't
>   want to install anything I don't need.

MAMP has all the files stored on his own, in his own versions.
You don't have to run a local MySQL-Server if you want to connect to a remote server. You just have to install the mysql-libraries for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you can do these line on your mysql query browser or something

```
SET old_passwords = 0;
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password = PASSWORD('testpass') WHERE User = 'testuser' limit 1;
SELECT LENGTH(Password) FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'testuser';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

note:your username and password

after that it should able to work. I just solved mine too